# Get HttpCookie property

Tags: c#, httpcookie

I'm trying to convert the following line from VB to C#:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("MyCookieName")("MyProperty")
```

I can get the cookie:

```
HttpCookie httpCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("MyCookieName");
```

but don't know how to get the property. Is "property" the correct word for what I am trying to get? How do I get this?

Answer:
    string property = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["MyCookieName"]["MyProperty"];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["MyCookieName"]["MyProperty"]`

That is the equivalent line in C#.  Those are indexers.

Comment: This line, with a ; at the end, does not compile. The error is:  Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

Comment: It's a partial statement.  You have to do something with the return value.  It doesn't make sense to fetch a value and let it sit in the abyss...  Just prepend `string cookieValue = ...;` where `...` is the code above, to the beginning of the line of code to store the result in a variable you can use.